# AndroidStudio3.0 to create a new project why Graphics so high

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Why 3.0 new Android Profiler the newly created project Graphics will be so high? Initially thought that the project had a problem, until I created a new project, which is why?

[image: new project memory]

Thank you all for helping me

Comment: Why do you think it is high?

Comment: Because the previous AndroidProfiler show my project is only about 50M, now show my project has 100 +

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html#how-counted) that says the calculation method has changed, so you cannot really compare the value with the previous version.

Comment: thank you~♪(＾∀＾●)ﾉ